# Bigfoot good guy?

Tags: magical-creatures

Was the cryptozoological creature known as “Bigfoot” ever a good guy in films/tv shows outside of “Harry and the hendersons”? I’m asking mostly for curiosities sake and I’m not sure if this question had ever been asked before. I would ask it on the movies and tv list,but I’m no longer allowed to ask questions on it unfortunately.

Comment: I was going to suggest the Six Million Dollar Man, except in that Bigfoot was a cyborg created to protect a colony of aliens living in secret.

Comment: If you're busy looking for whether there's a case, or for the earliest one, that's cool. Asking for a list of examples is not. :)

Comment: I’m mostly looking for the earliest one @FuzzyBoots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [*Bigfoot and Wildboy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot_and_Wildboy) (1977-1979)

— YouTube: [Bigfoot and Wildboy Theme (Intro & Outro)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMGXF5e7530)

The opening narration sums it up:

> "Out of the great Northwest comes the legendary Bigfoot, who, eight years ago, saved a young child lost in the vast wilderness, and raised that child until he grew up to be Wildboy."

Comment: @AbrahamRay — Thanks for accepting! It's still pretty early, so someone may post a better answer (eg, with more examples). If that happens, then please feel free to accept that answer instead.

Comment: Will do @Gaultheria will do

Comment: um, I'm getting an error in your post, whatever link, etc that was to be inserted.

Comment: @Megha — YouTube is having trouble right now, with direct links, too, not just inline like this one. It should clear up shortly.

Comment: @Gaultheria - thanks, its good to know.